# Oracle REGEXP_LIKE - search string not followed by specific character

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, regex-negation

I am looking to match string which is not followed by one character but can be followed by 0 or more of any other characters using REGEXP_LIKE in Oracle. 
For example, if I have these records:

```
ABCD
ABCDE
ABCDGH
ABCDF
ABCDUYR
```

I need to get all except ABCDE

I tried `REGEXP_LIKE(column,'^ABCD[^E]')`
But this also omits ABCD.
Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 REGEXP_LIKE(column,'^ABCD[^E]*')
```

`*` matches zeros or more characters

Comment: this would return `ABCDE` too.

Comment: ...and on the other hand it will reject ABCDJKE, which it should not reject.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude strings that contain `E` followed by `ABCD` use

```
REGEXP_LIKE(col,'^ABCD([^E]|$)')
```

`^ABCD([^E]|$)` - ABCD followed by any character(s) other than E or the string ABCD and no other characters after that.